# How can I reuse my explicit column selection?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a simple expression that I am using in my queries:

```
private Expression<Func<Account, NewAccount>> DefaultColumns {
    get {
        return o => new NewAccount() {
            Name = o.Name,
            Id = o.Id
        };
    }
}
```

I can use it in my queries like so:

```
await this.context.Accounts.Where(o => o.Id == id).Select(DefaultColumns).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

No problems there.  However, some of my queries use the query syntax:

```
var q = from a in context.Accounts

        join c in context.Contracts
        on a.Id equals c.AccountId

        where c.Id == id

        select a;
```

How can I use my explicit column definitions with that method of querying?  I don't want to define these column selections in multiple places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not like this?

```
var q = (from a in context.Accounts
    join c in context.Contracts
    on a.Id equals c.AccountId
    where c.Id == id
    select a).Select(DefaultColumns);
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't like that:  `A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause`

Comment: Ohh thats right i dont use this format often... Why not like this though?

Comment: Because that would be too easy!  Just kidding, that works perfectly, thank you.  For some reason I had the idea stuck in my head that the query sent to the database server would then query all the columns.  But, this makes sense as the query isn't sent to the server until we attempt to iterate over the `Queryable`.  It's definitely time for me to call it a day.